# Icon not displaying in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have used actionbar in my app. I have 3 icons on actionbar, but when the app runs it only shows 2 icons i.e. First and the last one, not mid one. I want to show all of them everytime.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<!-- Share, should appear as action button -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Generate QR"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

**<!-- NOT SHOWING THIS ONE -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Generate QR"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>**

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_nav_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Menu"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: i have used "always" in yourapp:showAsAction of every item and it is working well. Is this method is fine?

Comment: if its working as you want than its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want all 3 items to be displayed every time, include `yourapp:showAsAction="always"` in each item.